# check comma separated field against comma separated value in mysql

Tags: mysql

A table field has values has 1,2,3 (comma seperated value) and a variable has 2,3. Now i need to check weather variable value is in table field using query along with another name field

user table

```
id name   cat_id
-----------------
1  test   1,2,3
2  test1  3,4
3  test2  4
```

variable $value = 2, 3

Query : `select * from user where name='test' and cat_id IN ('".$value."')`

but for above query i get zero data

How to check if given id is exist in cat_id field and name exist in table

Comment: Don't have comma separated values, or don't use a relational database management system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex to check whether the value is contained in cat_id:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE name='test' AND cat_id REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', value, '[[:>:]]')
```

this will attempt to match `value` at any word boundary in `cat_id`, so for `cat_id='1,2,3'`, values of (for example) `'1,2'`, `'2'`, `'2,3'` will match.

To put it in a string form (e.g. for PHP):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE name='test' AND cat_id REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]','" . $value. "', '[[:>:]]')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `cat_id` field should contain only one `id` by row.

It's normal that your SQL request doesn't work currently because you're looking for cat_id `2` or `3` which SQL is not finding.

For example in your first row `1,2,3`, for MySQL it's a string "1,2,3" and not an array of three ids.

If a name can be used by several cats maybe they should be the ones having a `name_id`.

And if a cat can have several names, and a name can have several cats, you should create a new table `cats_names` containing one `name_id` and one `cat_id` by row.

Comment: I want name should not be duplicated. So while adding i am checking if that name has cat_id is matching with variable if matched exit or we do insert or update query. 
Based on cat_id is present or not

Comment: You would still be able to do those checks in those architectures I recommend you. It's really not a good practice to keep several ids as a string in a field of a MySQL DB.